# ||, && operators in C

Tags: c, logical-operators, logical-or, logical-and

Why this code only work with `&&` operator?

I think it should be `||`, but I'm wrong. `Choice` can not be equal to 2 value at the same time?

I need to ask user's input until choice will be equal  to `'a'` OR `'d'`, but why I need to write `&&` ?  I don't get it.

```
do
{
    scanf("%c", &choice);
} while ( choice != 'a' && choice != 'd' );
```

I wanted to use `||`, but it's not working.

Comment: Check _DeMorgan's laws_ [here](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with *how* the operators work, you need to get the logic for the code here.

First, a `do...while` loop operates as long as the condition in the `while` is TRUE.

In your case, you want to ask user's input until choice will be equal to `'a'` OR `'d'`.

- So, in other way, as long as user input is not equal to `a` and `d`, you need to loop.
- Logically, if the input is not equal to `a`, it can *still* be equal to `d`, so you have to check both the cases there. Only when, **none** of `a` or `d` is the input, you continue the loop.

Remember, you're not checking the equality, you're checking the **unequality**. Only if both the inequalities are satisfied, then only the `while` condition evaluates to TRUE_ and you continue looping to ask for new value(s).

***In a nutshell, [read DeMorgan's laws](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#DeMorgan.27s_laws).***

Answer (score 5):

You can use `||`. You need to change `while` loop conditional expression as follows

```
while ( !(choice == 'a' || choice == 'd') );
```

It's just an application of [DeMorgan's Law](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), how a not affect the AND & OR

```
______   ___  ___
A || B =  A && B
______   ___  ___
A && B =  A || B
```

Remember it as: "Break the line, change the sign".

```
INPUT   OUTPUT 1        OUTPUT 2
A   B   NOT (A OR B)    (NOT A) AND (NOT B)
0   0          1                 1
0   1          0                 0
1   0          0                 0
1   1          0                 0

INPUT   OUTPUT 1        OUTPUT 2
A   B   NOT (A AND B)   (NOT A) OR (NOT B)
0   0           1               1
0   1           1               1
1   0           1               1
1   1           0               0
```

Answer (score 5):

> I need to ask user's input until choice will be equal to 'a' OR 'd'

This condition can be written like

```
choice == 'a' ||  choice == 'd'
```

So if you want that the loop would iterate until this condition is true you should write

```
do
{
    //...
} while ( !( choice == 'a' ||  choice == 'd' ) );
```

Or if to include header

```
#include <iso646.h>
```

then you can write

```
do
{
    //...
} while ( not ( choice == 'a' ||  choice == 'd' ) );
```

or even like

```
do
{
    //...
} while ( not ( choice == 'a' or  choice == 'd' ) );
```

The condition

```
!( choice == 'a' ||  choice == 'd' )
```

or

```
not ( choice == 'a' or  choice == 'd' )
```

is equivalent to

```
!( choice == 'a' ) &&  !( choice == 'd' )
```

or

```
not ( choice == 'a' ) and  not ( choice == 'd' )
```

that in turn is equivalent to

```
( choice != 'a' ) &&  ( choice != 'd' )
```

The parentheses can be omitted Thus you will have

```
do
{
    //...
} while ( choice != 'a' &&  choice != 'd' );
```

Comment: Thank you Vlad nice explanation! I think I got it.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the condition with this one:

```
while (!(choice == 'a' || choice == 'd'));
```

Using this condition `do-while` statement will be executing until choice equals 'a' or 'd'.

Comment: This only works so :while ( !(choice == 'a' || choice == 'd') );

Comment: need another pair of parentheses

Answer (score 3):

hey it won't work because you want it to be not equal to a and b.

```
not equal to a and not equal to b

so it will be !( eqaul to a or eqaul to b) (De morgan's)
```

De Morgan's Law says

```
not( a and b)  = not (a) or not(b)
```

Here I applied simply that.

Answer (score 3):

If you wan to use the or (`||`) operator, you have to apply the [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws):

Let's say a, and b are booleans, so

```
a || b <=> !a && !b

a && b <=> !a || !b
```

This,

```
while ( choice != 'a' && choice != 'd' );
```

is the same as

```
while !( choice == 'a' || choice == 'd' );
```